# Add style element to html in a TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to write tag helper. I reached a result like below. I would like to read your negative comments, if any.

In an ASP.NET Core View I have the following:

```
<div style-height="100px">test</div>
```

And I the a Tag Helper with the following TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = StylePrefix + "*")]
public class SetStyleTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string StylePrefix = "style-";
    [HtmlAttributeName("style")]
    public string CssStyle { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, string> _styleValues;

    [HtmlAttributeName("", DictionaryAttributePrefix = StylePrefix)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> StyleValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _styleValues ?? (_styleValues =
                new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
        set { _styleValues = value; }
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var item = _styleValues.First().Key;
        var value = _styleValues.First().Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssStyle))
        {
            item.Insert(0, CssStyle);
        }

        if (item.Any())
        {
            output.Attributes.Add("style", item + ":" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After reproducing your code, I found that this method is not applicable when your handles multiple styles, such as `<div  style-color="red" style-font-size="36px">Test code</div>`. You can use a foreach to traverse all the styles in the dictionary to build a string and then concatenate this string.

Comment: Can you help me where should I use foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your process method you can try this:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
     var MystyleBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (var style in _styleValues)
     {
         MystyleBuilder.Append($"{style.Key}:{style.Value}; ");
     }

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssStyle))
     {
         MystyleBuilder.Insert(0, CssStyle + "; ");
     }

     if (MystyleBuilder.Length > 0)
     {
         output.Attributes.Add("style", MystyleBuilder.ToString());
     }
}
```

When I use  multiple styles:

```
<div  style-color="red" style-font-size="36px">
    Test code
</div>
```

I can see multiple styles are accepted:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to take it to the next level by checking dynamic incoming values as true false.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = StylePrefix + "*")]
public class SetStyleTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string StylePrefix = "style-";
    [HtmlAttributeName("style")]
    public string CssStyle { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, (bool Condition, string Text)> _styleValues;


    [HtmlAttributeName("", DictionaryAttributePrefix = StylePrefix)]
    public IDictionary<string, (bool Condition, string Text)> StyleValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _styleValues ??= new Dictionary<string, (bool, string)>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        set
        {
            _styleValues = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var MystyleBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var kvp in _styleValues)
        {
            if (kvp.Value.Condition)
            {
                MystyleBuilder.Append($"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value.Text}; ");
                
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CssStyle))
        {
            MystyleBuilder.Insert(0, CssStyle + "; ");
        }

        if (MystyleBuilder.Length > 0)
        {
            output.Attributes.Add("style", MystyleBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I use with condition styles:

```
 style-background-color='(true, "yellow")'

    style-background-color='(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.TopBarBackgroundColor), settings.TopBarBackgroundColor)'
```